# shell script get string from file between two strings

Tags: arrays, string, shell, awk, sed

I need to extract the string present in a file in  such a way that the string present after **input=** to before **output** 
In the below-specified example, I have three test cases and  i want to store the strings in an array

```
array[0]="3
45
60"
array[1]="10
62
12"
array[2]="5
72
12
67
89"
```

**Example** 
File.txt

```
case=test case 1
input=3
45
60
output=Enter the age:
Meenu got 27 coins

case=test case 2
input=10
62
12
output=Enter the age:
Meenu got 1000 coins

case=test case 3
input=5
72
12
67
89
output=Enter the age:
Meenu got 125 coins
```

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it. Given the tags you've included, I'd expect to see shell, awk and sed code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, here is a quick and dirty solution. Thanks for giving me a chance to practice `awk`. It works with `gawk`.

```
awk '/^case/, /^output/ {
#get case number
    if($0 ~ /^case/) {
        i=1
        s=""
        split($0, a)
        c = int(a[3]) - 1
    }
#get first input
    if($0 ~ /^input/) {
        split($0, b, "=")
        arr[i++]=int(b[2])
    }
#get other inputs
    if($0 ~ /^[0-9]+/) {
        arr[i++]=int($0)
    }
#print formatted string
    if($0 ~ /^output/) {
        for(j=1;j<i-1;j++){
            s=s""arr[j]"\n"
        }
        s=s""arr[i-1]"\"\n"
        printf("array[%d]=\"%s", c, s)
    }
}' File.txt
```